# Android UI Items in a ListView View

Tags: android, listview

I am not quite sure where to put the code for an onItemClickListener for multiple different buttons in a Listview (see below).  I have a delete, edit, and an on/off switch which I want to be able to deal with from this list.  Where do I implement this listener and what is the best way to do this?

Thanks!

[image]

My Adapt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your custom adapter , before the "return convertView"
add to everybutton its onClicklListener here is an exemple of adapter for list item with popup menu (like google play lis Items):

the Adapter

```
 public class MedecinListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
           private Activity activity;
        private LayoutInflater inflater;
        private List<MedecinItem> MedecinItems;

        public MedecinListAdapter(Activity activity, List<MedecinItem> MedecinItems) {
            this.activity = activity;
            this.MedecinItems = MedecinItems;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return MedecinItems.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int location) {
            return MedecinItems.get(location);
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            if (inflater == null)
                inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity
                        .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            if (convertView == null)
                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.medecin_list_item, null);


            TextView nom = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.NomMed);
            TextView specialite = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.SpeMed);
            TextView adresse = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.AdreMed);
            TextView numero = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.NumMed);

            ImageView imageMed = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView3);

            ImageView image = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
            final  MedecinItem item = MedecinItems.get(position);

            nom.setText(item.getNom());
            numero.setText(getString(R.string.numero)+":"+item.getNumero());
            adresse.setText(getString(R.string.adresse)+":"+item.getAdresse());
            if(Locale.getDefault().getLanguage().equals("ar"))
                specialite.setText(avoirSpeEnArabe(item.getSpecialite()));
            else
                specialite.setText(item.getSpecialite());
            String spe=avoirSpeEnFrancais(item.getSpecialite());

            System.out.println("spe '"+spe+"'");
            int  id = getResources().getIdentifier(avoirSpe2(spe).toLowerCase(), "drawable", getPackageName());

            imageMed.setImageResource(id);
            image.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(MainActivity.context, v);
                    popup.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.medecin_list_menu,
                            popup.getMenu());
                    popup.show();
                    popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item2) {
                            line2=item.getNumero();
                            Emailm=avoirEmail(line2);
                            switch (item2.getItemId()) {
                                case R.id.Appeler:
                                Call(item.getNumero());

                                    break;
                                case R.id.EnvoyerMsg:
                                    msg(Emailm);

                                    break;
                                case R.id.AfficherDet:

                                    menuItem = "3";
                                    Vider();
                                    telecharger();

                                    break;
                                case R.id.Afficher:

                                    String Lat;
                                    String Lon;
                                    Cursor medecin = MainActivity.db.lireMedecin();
                                    while (medecin.getPosition() < medecin.getCount()) {
                                        if (medecin.getString(4).equals(line2)) {
                                            Lat = medecin.getString(5);
                                            Lon = medecin.getString(6);
                                            Mapfrag2.map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(Lat), Double.parseDouble(Lon)))
                                                    .title(item.getNom())
                                                    .snippet(line2).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                                                            .fromResource(Icone(medecin.getString(7).charAt(0)))));
                                            MainActivity.vp.setCurrentItem(1, true);
                                            CameraUpdate zoom = CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(15);
                                            CameraUpdate center = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(Lat), Double.parseDouble(Lon)));
                                            Mapfrag2.map.moveCamera(center);
                                            Mapfrag2.map.animateCamera(zoom);
                                        }
                                        medecin.moveToNext();
                                    }

                                    break;
                                case R.id.AvoirRdv:
                                    telecharger();
                                    menuItem = "2";

                                    break;

                                default:
                                    break;
                            }

                            return true;
                        }
                    });

                }
            });
            if (!MedecinItems.get(position).anime){
                Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(MainActivity.context, R.anim.fade_in);
                convertView.startAnimation(animation);
                MedecinItems.get(position).anime=true;}

            return convertView;
        }

    }
```

instead remove that popup menu .. and dothe same thing for every button ..

here is how to use it :

```
MedecinListAdapter mla=new MedecinListAdapter(MainActivity.this,medecinItems);
        ((ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView)).setAdapter(mla);
```

where the "medecinItems" is the ArrayList

just modify this code and you are ready to go

Answer (score 1):

In your activity/fragment create separate `OnClickListener` for each button in your list item, pass them you your adapter and and set them in `getView()` method in your adapter.
Remember to call `setTag(getItem(position))` on each button in `getView()` so that in `onClick(View view)` you could call :

`YourListItemInstance item = (YourListItemInstance) view.getTag()`

This way proper listener will be called after specific button is clicked and you will exactly know which list item is involved.